# are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have two file first one is VehicleMaster.aspx.cs and another is class Vehicle.cs
When I want to access functions from my Vehicle.cs It gives me error that are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

VehicleMaster.aspx,.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using CarRentalERP.DL;
using CarRentalERP.BL;


namespace CarRentalERP
{
    public partial class Vehicle : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Vehicle objvehicle = new Vehicle();

            string value = objvehicle.RegVehicle1(txtvehicleno.Text.Trim(), txtvehicletype.Text.Trim(), txtvehiclename.Text.Trim(), txtVehiclemodel.Text.Trim(), Convert.ToInt32(txtyearofpassing.Text.Trim()),
                                                    txtinsuranceexpirydate.Text.Trim(),txtvehivleregistrationdate.Text.Trim(),Convert.ToInt32(txtvehicleregistrationno.Text.Trim()),
                                                    Convert.ToInt32(txtvehiclepermitno.Text.Trim()),txtvehiclepermitexpirydate.Text.Trim(),txtPUCExpirydate.Text.Trim(),txtengineno.Text.Trim(),
                                                    txtColor.Text.Trim(),txtclass.Text.Trim(),txtfueltype.Text.Trim(),txttaxexpirydate.Text.Trim(),Convert.ToInt32(txtseatingcapacity.Text.Trim()));
            long id = Convert.ToInt64(value);

            if (id > 0)
            {
                lblmsg.Text = "Register successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                lblmsg.Text = "Register Fail";
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Vehicle.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using CarRentalERP.DL;



namespace CarRentalERP.BL
{
    public class Vehicle
    {
        CarRantalERPEntities objcon = new CarRantalERPEntities();

        public string RegVehicle1(string VehicleNo,string VehicleType, string VehicleName, string VehicleModel,int YearOfPassing, DateTime InsuranceExpiryDate,
                               DateTime VehicleRegistrationDate,int VehicleRegistrationNo, int VehiclePermitNo, DateTime VehiclePermitExpiryDate,
                               DateTime PUCExpiryDate, string EngineNo, string Color, string Class, string FuelType, DateTime TaxExpiryDate,int SeatingCapacity)
        {
            string ID;
            try
            {
            VehicleMaster objVehicle = new VehicleMaster();

            objVehicle.VehicleNo = VehicleNo;
            objVehicle.VehicleType = VehicleType;
            objVehicle.VehicleName = VehicleName;
            objVehicle.VehicleModel = VehicleModel;
            objVehicle.YearOfPassing = YearOfPassing;
            objVehicle.InsuranceExpiryDate = InsuranceExpiryDate;
            objVehicle.VehicleRegistrationDate = VehicleRegistrationDate;
            objVehicle.VehicleRegistrationNo = VehicleRegistrationNo;
            objVehicle.VehiclePermitNo = VehiclePermitNo;
            objVehicle.VehiclePermitExpiryDate = VehiclePermitExpiryDate;
            objVehicle.PUCExpiryDate = PUCExpiryDate;
            objVehicle.EngineNo = EngineNo;
            objVehicle.Color = Color;
            objVehicle.Class=Class;
            objVehicle.FuelType = FuelType;
            objVehicle.TaxExpiryDate = TaxExpiryDate;
            objVehicle.SeatingCapacity = SeatingCapacity;


            objcon.VehicleMasters.Add(objVehicle);
            objcon.SaveChanges();

            }

            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                                                validationError.PropertyName,
                                                validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
           catch
           {
               ID = null;
               return ID;

           }
            ID = "1";
           return ID;
           }

    }
}
```

I got this error at objvehicle.RegVehicle1 line

Comment: can you trying adding using CarRentalERP; to your file Vehicle.cs and see it that helps

Comment: Have you added the reference from your BL project? After adding the reference in your Web Project you need to import the namespace `using CarRentalERP.BL;`

Answer (score 1):

Ah I see that your Vehicle class (The one that inherits from `object`) and the Vehicle class (The one that inherits `System.Web.UI.Page`) is in different namespaces. Their fully qualified name are:

```
CarRentalERP.BL.Vehicle

CarRentalERP.Vehicle
```

respectively. That is why you can't access `CarRentalERP.BL.Vehicle` from the `CarRentalERP` namespace. Normally you can add

```
using CarRentalERP.BL;
```

in your VehicleMaster.aspx,.cs file. However, you would have a name conflict if you do that. My advice is that you should rename your `CarRentalERP.Vehicle` class to something else and then the using statement would work.

If it still doesn't work, that means you didn't put the reference in. I assume you use Visual Studio. In the Solution Explorer, right-click References -> Add Reference and in the dialog, browse for your project or class library.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot for adding reference]

Add the reference to your BL as shown in the image.

then make the dll available to your class by adding below line.

```
using yourBLName;
```